# What, precisely, are the criteria for determining if a relay will be flagged as a guard?

Tags: relays, guard, flags

The [Tor FAQ's "What are Entry Guards?" entry](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#EntryGuards) does not describe the process by which a relay becomes a guard.  The word "flag" is not mentioned anywhere in the FAQ index.

[Arma's "The lifecycle of a new relay"
post](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay) lists three general criteria:

> Directory authorities assign the Guard flag to relays based on three
>   characteristics: "bandwidth" (they need to have a large enough consensus
>   weight), "weighted fractional uptime" (they need to be working most of the
>   time), and "time known" (to make attacks more expensive, we don't want to
>   give the [Guard flag](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/dir-spec.txt#l1685) to relays that haven't been around a while first).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been described in details in the phase three of [The lifecycle of a new relay](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay).

Your new relay has to be stable (up and running for at least 8 days), and have a minimum bandwidth of 250KB/s to receive a guard flag and become an entry node.

Here I quote from [Tor spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/dir-spec.txt#l1775):

> A router is a possible 'Guard' if its Weighted Fractional Uptime is at
>   least the median for "familiar" active routers, and if its bandwidth
>   is at least median or at least 250KB/s.
>
> To calculate weighted fractional uptime, compute the fraction of time
>   that the router is up in any given day, weighting so that downtime and
>   uptime in the past counts less. A node is 'familiar' if 1/8 of all
>   active nodes have appeared more recently than it, OR it has been
>   around for a few weeks.

Comment: I recently put up a fairly-fast relay, got the guard flag in 3 days, then lost it when it crashed due to a misconfiguration and was down for some hours. Has the behavior changed since your answer was written?

Comment: Can the people who are recently engaged in Tor Community write some comments here to update this answer to the December 2023 situation? Some statements in this answer are time resilient like `A router is a possible 'Guard' if its Weighted Fractional Uptime is at least the median for "familiar" active routers`, some other statements are more volatile: `and if its bandwidth is at least median or at least 250KB/s`. 250KB/s in October 2013 is not the same as 250KB/s in December 2023. So is this value still 250KB/s, or is it 500KB/s or 750KB/s nowadays?